# Smart Contract Logic for Dynamic Yield Distribution in ERC-4626-Based Promo Code NFTs

Tags: nft

I am implementing a feature an NFT feature NFT promo codes, using ERC-4626 (Tokenized Vault Standard) to create promo code NFTs that accrue yield over time. My question is focused on one specific technical challenge:

How can I implement a mechanism in the smart contract to accurately track and allocate yield to each NFT based on the duration it is held? I am seeking an efficient way to calculate and update the yield for each NFT in real-time or near-real-time.

Thanks in advance